# Chrome Extensions, separate storage partitions (Webview-like behaviour)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to get webview-like behaviour in a Chrome app. Specifically I mean the partition property.

Basically, I need different websites to load in different webviews with their own separate data.

For example, if someone has two webviews open and logs into facebook in view 1. View 2 will not have facebook logged in.

The partition property allows you to do that in Chrome Apps, but I can't seem to find anything that I could use for Chrome extensions, whether it be webviews or somehow doing it with iframes?

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode?

Comment: Not example, incognito does use it's own separate one from the main storage. However, the webview property described above allows you to create them at will.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697697/what-is-partition-attribute-for-webview-tag-in-chrome-app-api) if it can help you or give you an idea about your problem.

Comment: It only explains how to use the webview tag which I already know how to use. I need to emulate this sort of behaviour in an extensions where webviews aren't allowed.